# assertContains not getting the correct output how it is working?

Tags: php, phpunit

i have a code like this but the assertion is not working . $user6_notification has user8 and user10 , how can i check the user id is in the user notification? [assertContains](http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertContains)

```
foreach ($user6_notification as $notification) {
            $this->assertContains($user8["id"],$notification->userId);
        }
```

Comment: What does $user6_notification contain? Array of primitive or objects, what kind of object? Give us more detail please

Comment: @Aboca Array([0] => stdClass Object([_id] => stdClass Object(
                    [$id] => 537cb08eb0b80586268b4651
                )
            [userId] => user8
                    )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_id] => stdClass Object
                ([$id] => 537cb08eb0b80586268b4652)
            [notifierId] => user6
            [userId] => user10))

Comment: I think my way of iteration is wrong

Comment: Paste me the code used to construct $user6_notification please, i'm getting lost on the var_dump xD

Comment: $this->get('/users/notification/'.$user6["id"]);
        $user6_notification = json_decode($this->response->body());
        $this->assertEquals(2, count($user6_notification));

        foreach ($user6_notification as $notification) {
            print_r($notification->userId);
            $this->assertContains($user8["id"], array($notification->userId));
        }

Comment: I think you are evaluating user8 id with something not related to it, maybe you are actually looking for $notification->id, i'm not sure of what does $user8["id"] contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($user6_notification as $notification) {
    $this->assertContains($notification->userId, array($user8["id"], $user10["id"]));
}
```

Just changed the action in for loop. Got it.